# Problema no encuentra la propiedad

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en javascript, necesito acceder a la propiedad contenido="" pero no la encuentra.

HTML

```
   <select class="form-select form-control-sm" >
<option id="cuotas" contenido="12" value="{{$plan->interes}}">{{$plan->cuotas}} Cuotas</option>
 </select>
```

Js

```
const select = document.querySelector('.form-select');

console.log(select.contenido);
```

Error: **undefined**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día,

Te hace falta obtener la opción seleccionada y el atributo de la opción seleccionada

Ejemplo:

```js
// Obtener el select
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.form-select');

// Obtener la opción seleccionada
const selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex];

// Obtener el atributo "contenido"
const contenidoValue = selectedOption.getAttribute("contenido");

console.log(contenidoValue);
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-control-sm" >
  <option id="cuotas" contenido="12" value="{{$plan->interes}}">{{$plan->cuotas}} Cuotas</option>
</select>
```

De esta forma verás que en la consola se imprime `12`

### Edición

Si lo que pretendes es que el valor se actualice cada vez que cambie la opción, entonces puedes utilizar una función para obtener el atributo y utilizar esa función en `onchange` del `select`

```js
function getSelectedContenido() {
// Obtener el select
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.form-select');

// Obtener la opción seleccionada
const selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex];

// Obtener el atributo "contenido"
const contenidoValue = selectedOption.getAttribute("contenido");

console.log(contenidoValue);
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-control-sm" onchange="getSelectedContenido()">
  <option id="optionNull" contenido="0" value="{{$plan->interes}}">Selecciona...</option>
  <option id="optionA" contenido="12" value="{{$plan->interes}}">A</option>
  <option id="optionB" contenido="24" value="{{$otherPlan->interes}}">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Esta bien la solución, pero hay un problema, solo coge el valor de la primera opción del select

Comment: Buen día @jerex, hay que intentarle un poco antes de pedir ayuda mi chavo. El código que puse primero se ejecuta una sola vez y obtiene el atributo de la opción seleccionada. Al cargarse la página, la opción seleccionada es la primera. Si desearas que el valor del atributo se actualice entonces tendrías que usar una función. Si esa era la intención desde el principio, entonces creo que la pregunta no estaba clara. Edité la respuesta y agregué un ejemplo de como hacerlo. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Es que el asunto no funciona de esa manera (aunque no es mala idea).

Los atributos personalizados (*custom attribute*) de un elemento HTML no crean una propiedad en un objeto javascript de forma automatica. Pero puedes usar `getAttribute`

Ejemplo

```js
const undiv = document.getElementById("undiv");

console.log(  undiv.unatributo     ); //no existe
console.log(  undiv.getAttribute("unatributo")     ); // Si existe
```

```html
<div id="undiv" unatributo="unvalor"></div>
```

---

Por otro lado, si usas el prefijo `data-` si es posible acceder automáticamente, usando la propiedad `dataset`

```js
const undiv = document.getElementById("undiv");
console.log(  undiv.dataset.unatributo     );
```

```html
<div id="undiv" data-unatributo="unvalor"></div>
```

---

Adicionalmente tu código tiene otro error, tu haces `const select = document.querySelector('.form-select');` esto te lleva al `<select>` no al `<option>` que es el que tiene el atributo `contenido`

Debes hacer lo siguiente para obtener el valor del atributo "contenido" del `option` cuyo id es `cuotas`

```
const option = document.querySelector('#cuotas');
console.log(option.getAttribute("contenido") );
```

O, si quieres el option seleccionado:

```
const option = document.querySelector('.form-select > option:selected');
console.log(option.getAttribute("contenido") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproduciendo tu problema, tu tienes lo siguiente:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.form-select');
console.log(select);
console.log(select.contenido);
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-control-sm" >
  <option id="cuotas" contenido="12" value="{{$plan->interes}}">{{$plan->cuotas}} Cuotas</option>
</select>
```

Véase que en la variable `select` se almacena el contenido HTML de ese `select`, y estás intentando ingresar a `contenido` como si fuese una propiedad.

*Recuerda, `contenido` no es una propiedad, sino un atributo.*

---

Si te das cuenta, el atributo `contenido` proviene de la etiqueta `option`, por lo que primero tendrías que ingresar al `option` correspondiente del `select` capturado, que sería la primera opción (ya que por defecto es la opción seleccionada). entonces utilizamos `select.options[select.selectedIndex]`, en donde `select.selectedIndex` es la opción que está seleccionada:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.form-select');
console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex]);
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-control-sm" >
  <option id="cuotas" contenido="12" value="{{$plan->interes}}">{{$plan->cuotas}} Cuotas</option>
</select>
```

Y una vez al haber ingresado a esa opción, recién obtenemos el valor de su atributo `contenido` con `getAttribute('contenido')`:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.form-select');
console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('contenido'));
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-control-sm" >
  <option id="cuotas" contenido="12" value="{{$plan->interes}}">{{$plan->cuotas}} Cuotas</option>
</select>
```

Y respecto a tu comentario:

> *Esta bien la solución, pero hay un problema, solo coge el valor de la primera opción del select.*

Sucede porque el código obtiene el valor del atributo `contenido` de la opción seleccionada por defecto (que sería la primera opción), y debido a tu comentario, asumo que tienes un grupo de varias opciones, por ejemplo:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.form-select');
console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('contenido'));
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-control-sm">
  <option contenido="12" value="0">- Seleccione -</option>
  <option contenido="13" value="1">opción 1</option>
  <option contenido="14" value="2">opción 2</option>
  <option contenido="15" value="3">opción 3</option>
</select>
```

Entonces, tendrías que utilizar un listener con el evento `change` para indicar que cuando se cambie de opción en tu `select`, escuche al evento y vuelva a obtener el valor del atributo `contenido` de la opción que se seleccionó, por ejemplo:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.form-select');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const contenidoSeleccionado = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('contenido');
  console.log(contenidoSeleccionado);
});
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-control-sm">
  <option contenido="12" value="0">- Seleccione -</option>
  <option contenido="13" value="1">opción 1</option>
  <option contenido="14" value="2">opción 2</option>
  <option contenido="15" value="3">opción 3</option>
</select>
```